# How do I avoid duplicates when working out Aggregate functions on related tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It happens a lot that I need to make up some calculations on some related tables, to simplify the problem I created these 3 tables:

**Transactions**

```
TransactionId CustomerId  SellerId    NetValue    Taxes
------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1             1           2           435         10
```

**TransactionDetails**

```
TransactionDetailId TransactionId ItemId      ItemPrice   Qty         IsNew IsOriginal
------------------- ------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----- ----------
1                   1             1           40          8           1     1
2                   1             2           50          2           0     1
3                   1             3           15          1           1     0
```

**Payments**

```
PaymentId   TransactionId PaymentValue PaymentMethodId
----------- ------------- ------------ ---------------
1           1             50           1
2           1             300          2
```

Now I need to get a one-row table like this:

```
NewItems    NewItemsValue OriginalItems OriginalItemsValue ItemsValue  TotalItems  Paid        Visa        Cash
----------- ------------- ------------- ------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
9           335           10            420                435         11          350         300         50
```

I first tried this (before applying `SUM` function):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Detail.IsNew = 1 THEN Detail.Qty END AS NewItems,
CASE WHEN Detail.IsNew = 1 THEN Detail.ItemPrice END AS NewItemsValue,
CASE WHEN Detail.IsOriginal = 1 THEN Detail.Qty END AS OriginalItems,
CASE WHEN Detail.IsOriginal = 1 THEN Detail.ItemPrice END AS OriginalItemsValue,
Pay.PaymentValue AS Paid,
Detail.ItemPrice AS ItemsValue,
Detail.Qty AS TotalItems,
(CASE WHEN Pay.PaymentMethodId=1 THEN Pay.PaymentValue ELSE 0 END) AS Cash,
(CASE WHEN Pay.PaymentMethodId=2 THEN Pay.PaymentValue ELSE 0 END) AS Visa

FROM Transactions AS Trans

JOIN TransactionDetails AS Detail ON Trans.TransactionId = Detail.TransactionId 

JOIN Payments AS Pay 
 ON Trans.TransactionId = Pay.TransactionId
```

but there are duplicates. Now, my only option is to join the three tables with `UNION` but this seems a bad option, Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use sub-queries:

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM TransactionDetails AS DetailNew WHERE DetailNew.TransactionId=Trans.TransactionId AND IsNew =1) AS NewItems,
(SELECT SUM(ItemPrice*Qty) FROM TransactionDetails AS DetailNew WHERE DetailNew.TransactionId=Trans.TransactionId AND IsNew =1) AS NewItemsValue,
(SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM TransactionDetails AS DetailOriginal WHERE DetailOriginal.TransactionId=Trans.TransactionId AND IsOriginal =1) AS OriginalItems,
(SELECT SUM(ItemPrice*Qty) FROM TransactionDetails AS DetailOriginal WHERE DetailOriginal.TransactionId=Trans.TransactionId AND IsOriginal =1) AS OriginalItemsValue,
(SELECT SUM(ItemPrice*Qty) FROM TransactionDetails AS Detail WHERE Detail.TransactionId=Trans.TransactionId) AS ItemsValue,
(SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM TransactionDetails) AS TotalItems,
(SELECT SUM(PaymentValue) FROM Payments) AS Paid,
(SELECT SUM(PaymentValue) FROM Payments WHERE PaymentMethodId=2) AS Visa,
(SELECT SUM(PaymentValue) FROM Payments WHERE PaymentMethodId=1) AS Cash
FROM Transactions AS Trans
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `aggregation` but *conditional* :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Detail.IsNew = 1 THEN Detail.Qty ELSE 0 END) AS NewItems,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Detail.IsNew = 1 THEN Detail.ItemPrice ELSE 0 END) AS NewItemsValue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Detail.IsOriginal = 1 THEN Detail.Qty END) AS OriginalItems,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Detail.IsOriginal = 1 THEN Detail.ItemPrice ELSE 0 END) AS OriginalItemsValue,
       SUM(Pay.PaymentValue) AS Paid,
       SUM(Detail.ItemPrice) AS ItemsValue,
       SUM(Detail.Qty) AS TotalItems,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Pay.PaymentMethodId=1 THEN Pay.PaymentValue END) AS Cash,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Pay.PaymentMethodId=2 THEN Pay.PaymentValue END) AS Visa
FROM Transactions AS Trans JOIN 
     TransactionDetails AS Detail 
     ON Trans.TransactionId = Detail.TransactionId JOIN 
     Payments AS Pay 
     ON Trans.TransactionId = Pay.TransactionId
GROUP BY Trans.TransactionId;
```

Edit : You need `aggregation` before `join` :

```
 select TransactionId, 
        sum(case when IsNew = 1 then qty else 0 end) as NewItems,
        sum(case when IsNew = 1 then ItemPrice else 0 end) as NewItemsValue,
        sum(case when IsOriginal = 1 then Qty else 0 end) as OriginalItems,
        sum(case when IsOriginal = 1 then ItemPrice else 0 end) as OriginalItemsValue, count(*) as TotalItems, sum(PaymentValue) as paid
 from TransactionDetails AS Detail 
 group by TransactionId;
```

Comment: `NewItems` is 18 instead of 9